# Cordova Offline Translating

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a cordova hybrid app and I'm looking into adding language support.

What is the best way to add **offline** language support ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use i18next.js for offline language in cordova app

https://www.i18next.com/overview/getting-started

Comment: Thank you, looks solid. Will try.